# Does the module pattern require the use of an IIFE?

Tags: javascript, iife

In a Udacity lesson it says conflicting things about the module pattern:

> The Module Pattern requires the use of IIFE's

and

> At its core, the Module Pattern leverages scope, closures, and (commonly) IIFE's.

So, if I understand correctly, a module pattern requires the use of a closure, but does the closure need to be in an IIFE or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScript ECMAScript 5 and older, [an IIFE, or immediately-invoked function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), was necessary to create a function scope that prevented [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) declarations from polluting the global namespace when implementing the revealing module pattern.

```
(function () {
  var foo = 'bar'
  var counter = 0

  this.someGlobalModule = function () {
    counter++

    return { foo: foo, counter: counter }
  }
}.call(this))
// this === window at top-level in browser

// no access to function-scope foo or counter, only someGlobalModule()
var value = someGlobalModule()

// value.foo === 'bar'
// value.counter === 1
```

Now with JavaScript ECMAScript 6, the introduction of [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) and [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) declarations allow block-scope variables, as opposed to function-scope, so you can simply use a [block-scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) to implement the revealing module pattern:

```
{
  const foo = 'bar'
  let counter = 0

  // this === window at top-level in browser
  this.someGlobalModule = () => {
    counter++

    return { foo, counter }
  }
}

// no access to block-scope foo or counter, only someGlobalModule()
let value = someGlobalModule()

// value.foo === 'bar'
// value.counter === 1
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, when using var in a function, it is scoped to that function--so an IFFE is not needed. var is either global (when used outside of a function) or function scoped.

Comment: @Natalie you are correct that it is function-scoped, as I said in my answer. That's exactly why an IIFE is necessary to prevent it from polluting the global namespace, by preventing it from being globally-scoped.

Comment: Please use semicolons in your examples.

Comment: @Barmar No thank you, [I don't like semicolons](https://standardjs.com/).

Comment: But if a variable is declared with var in a function, it isn't visible in the global namespace, without the use of an IFFE. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: @Natalie the function itself would be visible to the global namespace, and it wouldn't be a module either.